# Passing shell variables containing spaces as arguments

Tags: shell, ffmpeg

I know there are many of these questions out there already, but my situation is unique enough that none of them have helped me thus far.

I'm writing a script that will reformat my (poorly tagged) music library. It's currently in the form of Music/Genre/Artist/Album/##-Title.wav.

From the Music directory, I run my script1, which calls `find -name "*.wav" -exec script2 {} ${other_args}`. Script2 parses the path to variables, creates the appropriate output directory if it doesn't exist, and then calls ffmpeg to do the compression.

ex: ($sourcefilepath contains {} from find)

```
ffmpeg -i "$sourcefilepath" "$path/$to/$outfile.$extension"
```

If my file name or path contains no spaces, it works like a charm.

If it contains spaces, ffmpeg fails, with the following error:

> Blues/Country Blues/Rhythm, Country And Blues/08-Natalie Cole & Reba
>   McEntire Since I Fell For You.wav: No such file or directory

Note: that's the source file it can't find. The output file appears to be working correctly, even with spaces. That's not the full command I'm running (it has some -metadata flags too, but that also appears to be working correctly. I'm debugging with the command I wrote above).

The interesting thing here is that ffmpeg is NOT interpreting $sourcefilepath as two args, it just can't find the file I specified. Running the following from the Music directory works.

```
ffmpeg -i Blues/Country\ Blues/Rhythm\,\ Country\ And\ Blues/08-Natalie\ Cole\ \&\ Reba\ McEntire\ \ \ Since\ I\ Fell\ For\ You.wav output.flac
```

I'm kind of stuck here. The other information on the web involves getting a command to see a variable with a space as one arg instead of multiple. I appear to have done that, but ffmpeg can't find my file now.

Normally I'd just use `find -name "*.wav" -exec ffmpeg -i {} ${args} \;` but I need to process the file path to extract my metadata.

I'm fairly new to shell scripting; does anybody know what's going on here?

Comment: Could you [remove everything that isn't vital](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) in your script, verify that it still exhibits the same problem, and add it to your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My psychic powers suggest that at some point in your code, you're doing something along the lines of:

```
something=$(echo $filename | something)
```

This should instead have been:

```
something=$(echo "$filename" | something)
```

Here's a script demonstrating why this is a problem:

```
#!/bin/sh
filename="Reba McEntire   Since I fell"    
echo "$filename"    # Correct, quoted
echo $filename      # Incorrect, unquoted
```

It outputs:

```
Reba McEntire   Since I fell
Reba McEntire Since I fell
```

You'll notice that

- the first line has **three spaces** after the artist, as in your correct command.
- the second line has **one space** after the artist, as in your error message.

This is due to unquoted variable expansion undergoing wordsplitting. `echo` then concatenates the arguments with single spaces. The net result is multiple whitespace coalescing into one space.

Comment: Your psychic powers were correct; I was passing variables to sed and cut that way, to process the path. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JulianDelphiki For your convenience, [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) automatically points out this and other issues.